# Capture the answers from form within while loop

Tags: php

I want to capture answers from forms within a big loop and then update the results into database. I am not sure how to do that, I have made a sample code as follows, and want to for each Save button save each question results. Say we have 5 questions, when I click save botton 1, save answers for question 1; when click save button , save answers for question 2..
Thanks very very much, this drove me crazy.....

```
<?php
$x=1;
$output="";

while($x<=5){
    $output .= "<form action='index.php' id='" . $x . "' method='POST'>";
    $output .="<h2>Question" . $x . "</h2>";
    $output .= "<h3>selection</h3>";
    $output .= "<ul><li><input type='radio' name='selection" . $x . "' value='1'>1</li>";
    $output .= "<li><input type='radio' name='selection" . $x . "' value='2'>2</li>";
    $output .= "<li><input type='radio' name='selection" . $x . "' value='3'>3</li></ul>";

    $output .= "<h3>choice</h3>";
    $output .= "<ul><li><input type='radio' name='choice" . $x . "' value='a'>a</li>";
    $output .= "<li><input type='radio' name='choice" . $x . "' value='b'>b</li></ul>";

    $output .= "<p><textarea rows='4' cols='50' name='commentory" . $x . "' form='usrform' placeholder='Enter text here...'></textarea></p>";

    $output .= "<input type='submit' name='saveResult" . $x . "' value='Save'>";

    $output .= "</form>";
    $output .="<br>";



    $x++;
}

echo $output;

if(isset($_POST['saveResult' .$x])){
    $selection = $_POST['selection' . $x];
    $choice = $_POST['choice' . $x];
    $commentory = $_POST['commentory' . $x];
    $result=$selection . $choice . $commentory;
    echo "<script>alert($result])</script>";
    // This part just a sample part as I dont know how to capture the results
}


?>
```

Comment: cteate two files one for html and one for php. and use array instead count like `x++`

Comment: Hi, sorry I am new to this, could you help to provide more details? Some codes?Thanks heaps

Comment: sorry I am using my mobile. will definitely post an answer if get chance soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your current file, you could change the first line in the while loop to this:

```
$output .= "<form action='index.php?question=" . $x . "' id='" . $x . "' method='POST'>";
```

What this does is sends a *GET* request with a number, from 1-5, based on what question was submitted. You can then do something like this to differentiate between your five (or however many) questions:

```
$questionNumber = $_GET['question']; // The ?question= parameter sent in the URL

if($questionNumber == 1) {
    // Question 1 logic here
} else if($questionNumber == 2) {
    // Question 2 logic here
} ...
```

Or do the same thing using a switch statement:

```
switch($questionNumber) {
    case 1:
    // Question 1 logic here
    break;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply.
1. Is there a way to use id in form instead of 'index.php?question='?
2. This is a sample, in my real project, I will have more than 100 questions, so i cannot really use if or switch statement....

Comment: PHP can only get the **name** and **value** properties from forms, not the actual DOM IDs or classes. You could add a hidden input field on each form with the question number, but you're going to end up with the same result. A more secure way would be to put a unique id in the input field, validate it in a database, then only process the logic for it if the two values match. That way, users cannot edit your HTML and send the incorrect question number. Ex.:

    <input type="hidden" name="question1" value="<?php echo openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16, true); ?>" />